# Date formatted using ToString() with a custom format results in inconsistent output

Tags: powershell, csv, datetime, date-formatting

with a powershell script I'm exporting a list of all the DHCP Servers that exists and the scopes on the Server. The results has to be parsed in a second script in python. (Thats a system for our monitoring).

Here's the script:

```
$DHCPServers = (Get-DhcpServerInDC).Dnsname
$Scopes = @()
$Leases = @()
foreach ($DHCPServer in $DHCPServers) {
    $Scopes += Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $DHCPServer | select-Object @{Name="DHCPServer"; Expression = {$DHCPServer}},ScopeID,Name,StartRange,EndRange
}

$Scopes | Export-Csv -path .\DHCP_Freeleases-Scopes-get.csv -Encoding utf8 -NoTypeInformation

foreach ($Scope in $Scopes) {
    $Leases += Get-DHCPServerv4Lease -ScopeId $Scope.ScopeID -ComputerName $Scope.DHCPServer | select-Object @{Name="DHCPServer"; Expression = {$Scope.DHCPServer}}, IPAddress, @{Name="LeaseExpiryTime"; Expression = {$_.LeaseExpiryTime.toString("yyyy/MM/dd/HH:mm")}}, @{Name="ScopeID"; Expression = {$Scope.ScopeID}}, Addressstate
}

$Leases | Export-Csv -path .\DHCP_Freeleases-Leases-get.csv -Encoding utf8 -NoTypeInformation
```

While I wrote that script on my local DHCP Server (Windows Server 2012 R2) the CSV export was the way that I wanted it:

`"dhcp1.server.intern","10.26.9.202","2022/01/25/08:22","172.26.9.192","Active"`

Now I deployed the script to a different server (Windows Server 2019) and the exact same script gives me this CSVline:

`"dhcp1.server.intern","10.26.9.202","2022.01.25.08:22","172.26.9.192","Active"`

And I want to understand it: How can that be? I thought .toString() gives it out with my parameters?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: i presume you are talking about the changed date delimiters? if so that is usually a culture setting. if not ... please be more specific about what you are talking about. [*grin*]

Comment: Yes, I ment delimiter. Thanks for that, I didn't came up with that word doing my research 

Comment: i see that you have an Answer that works for you. _good to know!_  [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTime.ToString()` method treats the forward slash and the colon as format specifiers. This means that they can be replaced by locale-specific characters.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#escape):

> The "d", "f", "F", "g", "h", "H", "K", "m", "M", "s", "t", "y", "z",
> ":", or "/" characters in a format string are interpreted as custom
> format specifiers rather than as literal characters. To prevent a
> character from being interpreted as a format specifier, you can
> precede it with a backslash (), which is the escape character.

To enforce a fixed format just escape these characters by backslashes:

```
$_.LeaseExpiryTime.toString("yyyy\/MM\/dd\/HH\:mm")
```

As you noted in the comments, you may also use a [predefined format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings), such as 's' (ISO 8601), that is locale-independent by definition:

```
$_.LeaseExpiryTime.toString('s')
```

The output looks like `2022-01-25T11:20:26`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried that first and that worked. Reading the documentation showed me aswell that I can write an simpe `s` and it returns the ISO Format. Now I use that. 

Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Gamienator Good point, I've added it to my answer.